# Spell checker through powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am using Sitecore 9.1 with sxa 1.8. I need to check spelling on whole page ( has multiple components) using PowerShell script.

I have tried OOTB functionality for spelling option under Review menu. However, it shows the result for only one item in content editor only. I need to check for whole page.

[image]

Is there any way to check it through PowerShell script for all the components on the page in single request or is there any OOTB functionality to check spelling for whole page ( including all the components) in single request?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RichardSeal I would like to spell check of whole page through powershell script .